# Plastic Hinge by Skyciv

Tags: structural-engineering, moments

Is it possible to determine plastic hinge location of a frame in SkyCiv? Is it also possible determine moment -curvature relationship curve in SkyCiv? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is a physically (material) non-linear analysis of a frame. From the SkyCiv [documentation](https://skyciv.com/documentation/structural-3d/solving-the-structure/non-linear-analysis/):

```
The SkyCiv Non-Linear solver only takes into account geometric non-linearities.
```

You can use the linear elastic moment distribution to determine the point at which the first plastic hinge will occur (the point with the largest bending moment). However, without a physically non-linear analysis, you will not be able to model what happens after the first plastic hinge forms in one analysis run.

Comment: Note that it is possible to conduct a stepped analysis in which you first load until the plastic moment is reached. You then re-analyse the structure with a hinge at this location and with an applied moment equal to the plastic moment to determine the next plastic hinge location. This process is repeated until a mechanism is formed.